# Weird Exceptions & internal error when Jrebel is turned on for JSF 2.2 project

Tags: java, jsf, jrebel

I am using **JRebel** for my **JSF 2.2** project. My entire setup comprising of Myfaces 2.2 project running on Tomcat, using Netbeans 7.4 & JRebel was workng very fine but all of a sudden, it started giving out these exceptions whenever JRebel is now turned on. (When JRebel is off, application runs smooth) otherwise there are exceptions & internal errors.

```
INFO: Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
2014-02-14 02:21:31 JRebel: ERROR org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] getName() not found in java.util.List
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(JRebel:241)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.DefaultAnnotationProviderCBP$2.edit(DefaultAnnotationProviderCBP.java:42)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(JRebel:224)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(JRebel:91)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.instrument(JRebel:712)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.DefaultAnnotationProviderCBP.process(DefaultAnnotationProviderCBP.java:38)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(JRebel:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:257)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:246)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:230)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:120)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xE.transform(JRebel:50)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.DefaultAnnotationProviderFactory.resolveAnnotationProviderFromService(DefaultAnnotationProviderFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.DefaultAnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(DefaultAnnotationProviderFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.DefaultAnnotationProviderFactory.getAnnotationProvider(DefaultAnnotationProviderFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig(AnnotationConfigurator.java:90)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getAnnotationsFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:198)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:91)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:474)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: compile error: getName() not found in java.util.List
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(JRebel:723)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(JRebel:688)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JRebel:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(JRebel:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMethodArgs(JRebel:221)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(JRebel:709)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atNewExpr(JRebel:149)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.NewExpr.accept(JRebel:73)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMethodArgs(JRebel:221)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(JRebel:709)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(JRebel:688)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JRebel:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(JRebel:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(JRebel:242)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(JRebel:330)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(JRebel:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(JRebel:351)
2014-02-14 02:21:31 JRebel: Class 'org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultAnnotationProvider' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.DefaultAnnotationProviderCBP@org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@10e5b2d
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(JRebel:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(JRebel:569)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(JRebel:235)
    ... 41 more
```

..
..

```
2014-02-14 00:33:28 JRebel: Class 'org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.facelet.DefaultFaceletFactoryCBP@org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@1536e59
2014-02-14 00:33:28 JRebel: ERROR org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: getFacelet(..) is not found in org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredMethod(JRebel:1229)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.facelet.DefaultFaceletFactoryCBP.process(DefaultFaceletFactoryCBP.java:40)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(JRebel:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:257)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:246)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:230)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:120)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xE.transform(JRebel:50)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.getViewDeclarationLanguage(RewriteViewHandler.java:214)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.checkResourceExists(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:587)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.handleSuffixMapping(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:507)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.calculateViewId(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerImpl.java:122)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.deriveLogicalViewId(RewriteViewHandler.java:66)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

00:33:30.300 [http-bio-8080-exec-24] INFO  p.BusinessLayer.HelperClasses.Easy - ************Request recieved!**************   /netbeans-tomcat-status-test
2014-02-14 00:33:31 JRebel: ERROR org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] getFaceletPath(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) not found in org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.util.ResourceUtil
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(JRebel:241)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.facelet.DefaultFaceletCBP$1.edit(DefaultFaceletCBP.java:60)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(JRebel:192)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(JRebel:91)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.instrument(JRebel:712)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.facelet.DefaultFaceletCBP.patchGetRelativePathMethod(DefaultFaceletCBP.java:57)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.facelet.DefaultFaceletCBP.process(DefaultFaceletCBP.java:27)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(JRebel:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:257)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:246)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xU.a(JRebel:230)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(JRebel:120)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.xE.transform(JRebel:50)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createFaceletFactory(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2222)
2014-02-14 00:33:31 JRebel: Class 'org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.cbp.facelet.DefaultFaceletCBP@org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@1536e59
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.initialize(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2460)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.getViewDeclarationLanguage(RewriteViewHandler.java:214)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.checkResourceExists(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:587)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.handleSuffixMapping(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:507)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.application.DefaultViewHandlerSupport.calculateViewId(DefaultViewHandlerSupport.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerImpl.java:122)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.deriveLogicalViewId(RewriteViewHandler.java:66)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.deriveLogicalViewId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: compile error: getFaceletPath(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) not found in org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.util.ResourceUtil
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(JRebel:723)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(JRebel:688)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JRebel:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(JRebel:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(JRebel:242)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atDeclarator(JRebel:726)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Declarator.accept(JRebel:100)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(JRebel:351)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(JRebel:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(JRebel:351)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(JRebel:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(JRebel:569)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(JRebel:235)
    ... 60 more
```

and Tomcat logs:

```
Feb 14, 2014 12:33:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig(Ljavax/faces/context/ExternalContext;Z)Lorg/apache/myfaces/config/impl/digester/elements/FacesConfig;
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.util.JrMyFacesReloader.reloadAnnotations(JrMyFacesReloader.java:89)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Feb 14, 2014 12:33:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/error/pageNotExist.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig(Ljavax/faces/context/ExternalContext;Z)Lorg/apache/myfaces/config/impl/digester/elements/FacesConfig;
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.myfaces.util.JrMyFacesReloader.reloadAnnotations(JrMyFacesReloader.java:89)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    ... 22 more
```

Any idea what is causing this? How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible actions you can do to identify the cause:

1. Check the license information in the logs at server startup. I remember I had such a behaviour when my trial license expired.
2. Disable the myfaces jrebel plugin as described in this documentation: zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/frameworks. There is a configuration reloading feature which does not seem to be supported for version 2.2 of myfaces. . Disabling this feature will not impact class reloading which should remain functional.

Comment: Ok. Looking at jrebel support documentation in http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/frameworks/  , I see that there is a configuration reloading feature which does not seem to be supported for version 2.2 of myfaces. Disable the corresponding jrebel plugin as described in the documentation. This will disable that feature but class reloading should remain functional.

Comment: yeah..exceptions were removed but don't know why CPU usage is getting too high, which is not the case when JRebel is off..

Comment: I'm glad to know that you fixed the exception problem. I re-edited my answer so that you can accept it. Concerning the CPU issue, I experienced it my self but it was not blocking in the context of my project. So I did not look deeper into it. I guess Jrebel is intercepting JVM calls and this is performance consuming. May be you should ask another question dedicated to it.

Comment: I am seeing similar behaviour in JRebel when used with Intellij.Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger; Server is starting fine when JRebel is not coming in picture.

Comment: @GuyBouallet Hello, I looked at the documentation but didn't find anything about how to disable myfaces jrebel plugin...can you help to provide more details?

Comment: I found the following property `rebel.load_embedded_plugins=false` but it seems that it will disable all plugins and not only the MyFaces one. Does anyone know any way to disable only some plugins selectively?.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this Tomcat <-> Jrebel <-> Eclipse Problem.

Solution:

1. Stop Tomcat
2. Remove all WebProjects from Server
3. Clean Tomcat
4. Clean Tomcat Working Directory
5. Add your Projects again
6. Start